# Вывод данных из двух и более таблиц в php + mysqli

Tags: php, sql, mysqli

Пишу поиск для сайта. Пытаюсь вывести данные из ДВУХ таблиц базы данных, но получаю ошибку

> Fatal error: Uncaught mysqli_sql_exception: Column 'name' in field
> list is ambiguous in C:\OpenServer\domains\shelter\pages\search.php:26
> Stack trace: #0 C:\OpenServer\domains\shelter\pages\search.php(26):
> mysqli_query() #1 {main} thrown in
> C:\OpenServer\domains\shelter\pages\search.php on line 26

Понимаю, что проблема в неверном написании запроса $sql. Прошу Вашей помощи. Спасибо.

[image: ошибка]

```php
  $servername = "localhost";
  $username = "root";
  $password = "";
  $dbname = "shelter";
  mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);
  $connect = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

  if (isset($_POST['submit-search'])) {
     $search = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $_POST['search']);
     $sql = "SELECT `name`, `description`, `imagePath` FROM `cats-find-home`, `dog-find-home`
     WHERE `name` LIKE '%$search%' 
     OR `description` LIKE '%$search%'";

     $result = mysqli_query($connect, $sql);
     $queryResult = $result;

        while ($result2 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {

           $name = $result2['name'];
           $description = $result2['description'];
           $imagePath = $result2['imagePath'];

           echo '<div class="item__catalog">';

           echo '<a href="#"><img src="' . $imagePath .'">';
           echo '<h1>'. $name .'</h1></a>';
  
        echo '</div>';
        }
    
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Написано, что колонка `name` есть в обеих таблицах и поэтому SQL не знает какой именно тебе нужно, из какой конкретно таблицы. Поэтому следует указать конкретно и точно, например, `SELECT  cats-find-home.name`  или если сделать алиасы на таблицы, то через алиасы

типа `SELECT u.name FROM users u`, где `u` - псевдоним для таблицы

Comment: Если честно, не совсем понимаю верный синтаксис в таком случае. $sql = "SELECT * FROM `cats-find-home.name`"; - не работает :(

Comment: что именно не работает? нужно в обратные кавычки заключать отдельно наименование таблицы и отдельно наименование колонки (можно только название таблицы)  Например `select \`tableName\`.name` или  `select \`tableName\`.\`name\``

Comment: Странно, но при таком синтаксисе выводится следующая ошибка: "Fatal error: Uncaught mysqli_sql_exception: Unknown database 'cats-find-home' "

Comment: Ты точно через обратные кавычки писал?

Comment: Попробовал так: $sql = "SELECT `name` FROM `cats-find-home`.`name`";

Comment: да, через обратные

Comment: А зачем ты пишешь cats-find-home.name в FROM?

Comment: Извиняюсь, я дурак :). Спасибо!